# color buses in pandapower network plot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pandapower

I want to choose the color for certain buses in the graph of a pandapower network. I use the `simple_plotly` function from [pandapower](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.0/plotting/plotly/built-in_plots.html), which works well. As a next step I use `create_bus_trace` [here](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.0/plotting/plotly/create_traces.html) to crate a trace. Finally I use `draw_traces` [here](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.0/plotting/plotly/create_traces.html#draw-traces) to draw those buses.

**PROBLEM:**
The trace appears in a separate plot. But I want the trace to be in the same plot as that, created with `simple_plotly(net)`

Here is, what my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandapower.plotting as pt
import pandapower as pp
import pandapower.networks as pn

net = pn.create_kerber_vorstadtnetz_kabel_1()
pt.simple_plotly(net)

color_buses = np.random.choice(net.bus.index, 33)
color_trace = pt.plotly.create_bus_trace(net, color_buses, color='red',
                                         trace_name='special buses')
pt.plotly.draw_traces(color_trace)
```

Any ideas, how to get both traces into one plot?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandapower.plotting as pt
import pandapower as pp
import pandapower.networks as pn
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'browser'

net = pn.create_kerber_vorstadtnetz_kabel_1()
fig = pt.simple_plotly(net)

how_much_buses = 33
color_buses = np.random.choice(net.bus.index, how_much_buses)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=net.bus_geodata.loc[color_buses, 'x'],
                         y=net.bus_geodata.loc[color_buses, 'y'],
                         mode='markers'))

fig.show()
```

So the trick was to directly work with the object returned by `simple_plotly` and use `add_trace`.
I also had to tell plotly.io to use the browser as standard renderer for the updated plot to appear on `fig.show()`.

This is what it looks like:

[image]